# Meaning of きれい in this sentence

Tags: meaning

Regarding a fossil that was dug out of frozen ground in Russia:

> 眠っているように見えるぐらい**きれい**でした。
>   (The cave lion fossil) was so *neat* that it seemed like it was sleeping.

I'm struggling to translate きれい in this sentence. Neither clean, neat nor pretty really seem to make sense. To be honest, I can't think of any English word that would fit this sentence well. Is there an obvious translation of きれい that I'm missing, or am I just over thinking it? It is from an article for children after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe trying to paraphrase it more than to directly translate it makes more sense here? In regards to fossils using something like *well preserved* seems to fit, e.g.

> The fossil was so well preserved, it looked as though the cave lion was merely sleeping.

Or something along those lines.

Comment: >well preserved 見事な適訳です！

Comment: Do you think a scientist would use きれい to mean 'well preserved' or is this just a simplification for children?

Comment: Now I am neither a scientist nor a native but personally I think just using 綺麗/きれい is not formal enough for a scientific or even news context.　○は化石として綺麗に保存されました personally feels more appropriate for news or (from https://www.kaseki7.com/items_fossil/di/428.html) something like  保存状態極上の○化石。 So to rewrite your sentence I guess 眠っているように見えるほど綺麗に保存された化石でした。 feels more formal, but again I am not qualified to give my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

It was so placid that it looked as if it was sleeping.